`corelgilua51` not found in lgi lua
I am trying to run the following code
local lgi = require("lgi")
local Gdk = lgi.Gdk
local Gtk = lgi.Gtk

Gtk.init()

-- Create a new window
local window = Gtk.Window({
    title = "LGI Test Window",
    default_width = 300,
    default_height = 200,
    on_destroy = Gtk.main_quit,
})

-- Create a label and add it to the window
local label = Gtk.Label({ label = "Hello, LGI!" })
window:add(label)
window:show_all()
Gtk.main()

But this is giving me the following error
lua: /home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/lgi/core.lua:14: module 'lgi.corelgilua51' not found:
    no field package.preload['lgi.corelgilua51']
    no file '/home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.lua'
    no file '/home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51/init.lua'
    no file './lgi/corelgilua51.lua'
    no file './lgi/corelgilua51/init.lua'
    no file '/home/username/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi/corelgilua51.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './lgi/corelgilua51.so'
    no file '/home/username/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.3/lgi.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'
    no file './lgi.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/lgi/core.lua:14: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/lgi/init.lua:19: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/lgi.lua:19: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    init2.lua:1: in main chunk

I have already set LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH, but installing lgi from luarocks does not have the corelgilua51, what could be the issues, the lgi only contain the following files:-
drwxr-xr-x. 1 username username   226 Nov 15 13:01 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 username username    30 Nov 15 13:05 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username 15928 Nov 15 13:01 class.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username 11130 Nov 15 13:01 component.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username   761 Nov 15 13:01 core.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username  3319 Nov 15 13:01 enum.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username  5939 Nov 15 13:01 ffi.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username  3403 Nov 15 13:01 init.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username  1090 Nov 15 13:01 log.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username  6217 Nov 15 13:01 namespace.lua
drwxr-xr-x. 1 username username   524 Nov 15 13:01 override
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username  1591 Nov 15 13:01 package.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username  7088 Nov 15 13:01 record.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 username username    15 Nov 15 13:01 version.lua

lua version 5.3.6, not upgraded to 5.4 as a project I am trying to use requires a lua version less than 5.4, how can a module be absent when installing from luarocks and any help would be appreciated. Please ask for any other information if required.

https://github.com/lgi-devs/lgi/issues/196

thanks @shingo, I couldn't find this issue, will write an answer for future readers.

The reason for this question is that the lib directory in the lgi's Makefile is hardcoded as /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1.
PREFIX = /usr/local
LUA_VERSION=5.1
LUA_LIBDIR = $(PREFIX)/lib/lua/$(LUA_VERSION)
LUA_SHAREDIR = $(PREFIX)/share/lua/$(LUA_VERSION)
...
mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)$(LUA_LIBDIR)/lgi
cp $(CORE) $(DESTDIR)$(LUA_LIBDIR)/lgi

As you can see in the question, when you use it in another version of Lua, the directory it searches for is /usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/lgi.so, which resulted in the error. The solution can be to modify the value of LUA_VERSION in the Makefile, or copy the output file to the correct directory, or change package.searchpath.
